# Validating different input types of html in angular

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I have a html file which looks like this,

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">  

<div class="field"style="padding:1%">
      <label>Pacs name</label>
      <input placeholder="Pacs Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="pacs.name" formControlName="pacName">
    </div>

  <select class="ui dropdown"  (change)="onChangeforDistrict()" [(ngModel)]="address.state" formControlName="state">
      <option *ngFor="let state of state" [ngValue]="state" [selected]="address.state.id == state.id">
      {{state.name}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>

<button class="positive ui right floated button">
          Save
      </button>


</form>
```

So the form above contains a input type text,dropdown. which is working fine in inserting the data into the database when i click the save button.

i want to restrict the user if he is clicking the save button without entering any data or not selecting any option in the dropdown. I want to display the error messages under the respective fields when user click the save button with wrong data. if user enters the correct data then save button should call the save method of the component.

I am new to angular 2/4 .. code someone brief me an idea or a piece of example code.. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything to accomplish it? For start you should become familiar with basic form validation techniques described in official docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: unrelated, but consider not having two bindings on your fields (formcontrol and ngModel) :)

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski : I am working on a design which was developed and made complicated. i tried with few ways but i was getting errors..soo i thought of asking the question straight way

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps:

1. you have to add a label tag with the massege you want
2. you have to add to the label *ngIf the "pacName" is required and click on
 
   submmit button.
3. you have to add "required" attribute to the input

```
<div class="field"style="padding:1%">
      <label>Pacs name</label>
      <input placeholder="Pacs Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="pacs.name" formControlName="pacName" required>
<label *ngIf="pacName.errors.required && addressForm.submitted" >This filed is required!!</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

for more information: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
if you work with bootstrap you can add `class="danger-text"` 
it will set red color to the text inside the label

Comment: i used your example but i got the error 'Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined'

Comment: maybe you miss something in your componente please read this:https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms